# Saving player name throughout script-launches

Tags: python, python-2.x, console, io

I would like to use this in a program to save users' names even after they relaunch the script. I was just wondering if there were some ways I could clean up this code.

Note: this currently was made to not support name changing, but could possibly be implemented in the future.

```
if os.path.isfile('names.json'): # if there is a file with names...
    text_file = open("names.json") # only open it in normal mode
else: # if not...
    text_file = open("names.json", "w+") # make one

if os.stat("names.json").st_size > 0:
    for line in text_file:
        if line.istitle():
            player_name = line
        else:
            player_name = console.input_alert('What is your name? ').title()
            text_file = open("names.json", "w")
            text_file.write(player_name)
            text_file.close()
else:
    player_name = console.input_alert('What is your name? ').title()
    text_file = open("names.json", "w")
    text_file.write(player_name)
    text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are reading all of the file and checking for `istitle()`. Here I make the assumption that if the file exists, it will always include the player name on the first line.

```
if os.path.isfile('names.json'):
  with open('names.json') as f:
    player_name = f.readline()
else:
  player_name = console.input_alert('What is your name? ').title()

with open('names.json', 'w') as f:      
    f.write(player_name)
```

If you want to read the entire file and check for `istitle()`:

```
player_name = None
if os.path.isfile('names.json'):
  with open('names.json') as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          if line.istitle():
              player_name = line

with open('names.json', 'w') as f:  
    if player_name is None:
      player_name = console.input_alert('What is your name? ').title()
    f.write(player_name)
```

You may notice that I do not close the files in either case. That is because the `with` statement takes care of that for us. See [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: Nice answer. However, I would be careful [checking for equality to None](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Also, I would add a quick section describing why you used `with` instead of the OP's method of `open`/`close`.

Comment: @hansn that's why I didn't pick this as the answer at first. The edit that inverted the logic had me confused.

Answer (score 4):

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

The first thing that jumps to the eye is the duplication in your code:

- `'names.json'` appears 4 times: you should not duplicate string literals like this, put it in a variable instead
- `console.input_alert('What is your name? ').title()` appears twice: you should not duplicate logic, put it in a function instead

#### Leaked resources

You open `names.json` at multiple points and don't always close the filehandle. This is a bad practice and could lead to strange bugs. As others have pointed out, use the `with ...` idiom, and try to organize your code to do it at one common place.

#### Naming

`names.json` is not a good name, for several reasons:

- The `.json` extension is misleading, because you're using plain text format, there's no JSON anywhere in your code
- The plural "names" suggests there will be more than one names, but this doesn't seem to be the case for you

Perhaps a better, more future-proof name would be `user.config`.

#### Encapsulation

Configuration management sounds like a good subject to capture in a class.

#### Putting it all together...

I would rewrite like this:

```
CONFIGFILE = 'user.config'


class ConfigManager(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def load_name(self):
        try:
            with open(self.path) as fh:
                line = fh.readline()
                if line.istitle():
                    return line
        except IOError:
            return

    def save_name(self, name):
        with open(self.path, 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(name)


def ask_name():
    return raw_input('What is your name? ').title()


config = ConfigManager(CONFIGFILE)
name = config.load_name()
if not name:
    name = ask_name()
    config.save_name(name)

print 'So your name is {} ...'.format(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have named the file 'names.json', it would seem more natural to use [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). Leaving that aside for now, I'll first review your current code, then suggest new:

```
if os.path.isfile('names.json'): # if there is a file with names...
    text_file = open("names.json") # only open it in normal mode
else: # if not...
    text_file = open("names.json", "w+") # make one
```

Two observations. First, like [hansn's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55670/31488) notes, a `with` block is the cleanest way to manipulate files. Second, it is often more Pythonic to "try and fail" than test and do (or as the docs put it, [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)).

So, I would do something like:

```
filename = 'names.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        name = parse_name(f.read())
except OSError: # also any parse error parse_name may raise
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        name = ask_name()
        f.write(format_name(name))
```

(Of course, if you just want write the name as a line, you can do away with parse/format and just read/writeline.)

---

Now, if you wanted to use JSON, parse/format would have natural implementations:

```
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        name = json.load(f)
except OSError, ValueError:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        name = ask_name()
        json.dump(name, f)
```

(Note that the above doesn't check that the json really contains a string, but why shouldn't someone be named `[42]`;)

Now the only thing left would be `ask_name()`, which could just be `console.input_alert('What is your name? ')` if you don't care about name format or length.